# How do I add PenTablet setting and PentabletDriverUX to screen recording in MacOS Catalina? There is no add or minus button there

Tags: macos, catalina, imac, settings, screen-recording

I tried following some instructions but it is only for browsers like Google Chrome and I can't add  PenTablet setting and PentabletDriverUX there.

Comment: Have you tried to drag and drop the application/file onto the window?

Comment: I've tried that but it wouldn't be added to the list.